# Can we Single API for more then one app in android

Tags: android, android-maps

I am developing app in android using MapView.I have already generated an API for google maps.

Can I use the same API for more then on applications?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all your apps are signed with the same certificate you can use the same key.

You need a new api key for each certificate you use.

From: http://code.google.com/android/maps-api-signup.html

> If you use different keys for signing development builds and release
>   builds, you will need to obtain a separate Maps API key for each
>   certificate. Each key will only work in applications signed by the
>   corresponding certificate.
>
> You also need a Google Account to get a Maps API key, and your API key
>   will be connected to your Google Account.

Comment: But each time i am generating new API,i am getting same API key as i got before...